# how to post in my page using facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post in my page using facebook-sdk

I have **permission** to manage my page but when I post using

```
fb_response = graph.put_wall_post('python put wall post',{},FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID)
```

return  value

```
Something went wrong: OAuthException (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Comment: i think you should get publish_stream permission too 
(i'm a php developer so cant tell you code is right or wrong :) )

Comment: 1) get the `publish_stream` permission 2) append the page `access_token`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the access token for the page, rather than the access token for the authenticated user. If you have he manage_pages permission, you can get the access token for any pages that the user is an administrator of by querying

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

You'll then get a json collection containing all the facebook pages the user has access to, with their name, id and access token. This is the token that you need to use when performing actions on that page

details about how to do this here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: See also http://wuilly.com/index.php/2011/02/28/posting-to-a-page-wall-with-the-facebook-sdk-in-python/, possibly.